# IntelliJ IDEA: Generate list of TODOs with Todo-text and according file

Tags: intellij-idea, todo

Is it possible in IntelliJ IDEA to generate a list of all todos, such that I have in each line of text the file and the todo-comment? I'd like to copy that information into an excel sheet for further processing.

The Todo Tool Window shows me a list, but I cannot copy that list without having a lot of additional information in my list (when I copy after expanding all entries of the list and marking them).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there is such feature in IntelliJ, however you can easily make a script to generate such file for you:

```
egrep -nr '(TODO|FIXME|XXX)' src/ | sed -e 's/: */: /g' > todos.txt
```

This will provide you plain text file with following structure:

```
src/main/java/com/example/App.java: 11: // TODO: fix this
src/test/java/com/example/AppTest.java: 20: // XXX: test
src/test/java/com/example/AppTest.java: 32: // FIXME: test
```

You can modify this basic command to tweak the structure of the output. For instance to generate CSV file which you can then open in Excel.